# Issue when using FlattenedTreeTableDataSource with CollectionTreeDataSource

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, oracle-jet

Requirement

1. Table with Pagiantion ( fetch 30 rows per WS call)
2. Row Expander - Get Child Collection
3. Child - Table with Infinity Scrolling

I planned to use, ojTable, oj.Collection, oj.Model
oj.PagingTableDataSource <- oj.FlattenedTreeTableDataSource <- oj.FlattenedTreeDataSource <- oj. CollectionTreeDataSource <- oj.Collection hierarchy

Code

### Model

```
define([
    "Model"
], function(Model) {
    "use strict";
    var Code = Model.extend({
        "urlRoot": "code",
        "idAttribute": "rowNum",
        "defaults": {
            "rowNum": null,
            "code": null
        }
    });
    return Code;
});
```

### Collection

```
define([
    "Collection"
    "../models/Code"
    ], function(Collection, Code){
        "use strict";
        var Codes = Collection.extend({
            url: "code",
            model: Code
        });
        return Codes;
});
```

### VM Code

```
self.codes = new Codes(null, collectionOptions);
self.treeDataSource = new oj.CollectionTreeDataSource(
        {
            root:self.codes,
            parseMetadata:function(model){
                var retObj = {};
                retObj['key'] = model.id;
                return retObj;
            },
            childCollectionCallback:function(col , model){
            ...
            }
        });

self.treeTableDataSource = new oj.FlattenedTreeTableDataSource(new oj.FlattenedTreeDataSource(self.treeDataSource));
self.dataSource = new oj.PagingTableDataSource ( self.treeTableDataSource );
```

### html

```
<table id="table" 
    data-bind="ojComponent: 
    {
        component: 'ojTable', 
        data: dataSource, 
        rowTemplate: 'row_temp', 
        columns:$component.columns
    }">
</table>
<div id="paging" data-bind="ojComponent: {component: 'ojPagingControl', data: $component.dataSource, pageSize: 10}">
</div>
<script type="text/html" id="row_temp">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <div data-bind="ojComponent: {
            component: 'ojRowExpander', 
            context: $rowContext}"></div>
      </td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

### Problems:

1) The Data in ojtable is "undefined" with key as well, though the array size is correct. Have tested the same collection with normal TableDataSource and works fine.

```
ojtable.js:8265 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
    at oj.TableDomUtils.hashCode (http://127.0.0.1:8080/js/libs/ojet/oj/v2.0.2/debug/ojtable.js:8265:14)
    at _refreshTableBodyRow (http://127.0.0.1:8080/js/libs/ojet/oj/v2.0.2/debug/ojtable.js:5296:52)
    at ._refreshTableBodyRow (http://127.0.0.1:8080/js/libs/jquery/jqueryui-amd-1.11.4.min/widget.js:4:1032)
    at _refreshTableBody (http://127.0.0.1:8080/js/libs/ojet/oj/v2.0.2/debug/ojtable.js:5256:20)
    at ._refreshTableBody (http://127.0.0.1:8080/js/libs/jquery/jqueryui-amd-1.11.4.min/widget.js:4:1032)
    at _refreshAll (http://127.0.0.1:8080/js/libs/ojet/oj/v2.0.2/debug/ojtable.js:5155:14)
    at ._refreshAll (http://127.0.0.1:8080/js/libs/jquery/jqueryui-amd-1.11.4.min/widget.js:4:1032)
    at .<anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:8080/js/libs/ojet/oj/v2.0.2/debug/ojtable.js:3826:18)
    at http://127.0.0.1:8080/js/libs/ojet/oj/v2.0.2/debug/ojtable.js:6681:39
```

2) I see the offset not being set by pagination in this case, but works as expected in normal table.

3) I see the WS call being done multiple times (fetching all the records though the fetch size is 30) on initial load where as it should just fetch the first 30 records.

4) Options literal used by oj.CollectionTreeDataSource with all its root/parseMetadata/childCollectionCallback is undocumented

Guys, 
Please do help here. Why is the data Undefined and there are multiple calls on load rather on pagiantion

OJET v2.0.2

I just happen to debug and found that the

ojcollectiontreedatasource.js

```
oj.CollectionNodeSet.prototype.getData = function(index)
{
    this._checkRange(index);
    return this.collection.at(index).attributes;
};
```

returns

```
Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}
```

Not sure why?

Comment: Did you get to resolve this issue? Is the first render of data happening on the UI or is it during pagination that the issue is observed?

Comment: It's at the initial stage itself. I believe this is a bug in OJET. Not sure how to log the bug.

Comment: I am currently able to show the root node in the DataGrid but on expansion , " collection.sort is not a function " error . I have noticed that _promises is coming undefined for the CollectionTree object .

Comment: Not sure if this will help you but in the internal source code, _fetchChildren() -> range has been set as {"start":0 , "count":21}. Im assuming since you have not overwritten this, the number of rows being passed to the ojComponent will be different due to which the error is arising. Please let me know if this is the problem.

Comment: FYI: this still happens in OJET v3.2.0

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. After debugging (a lot), it turned out the `oj.Model`s `idAttribute` pointed to a nonexistent field.

For example:

```
var CustCollection = new oj.Collection.extend({
    url : 'https://dev.example.com/app/rest/categories',
    model : new oj.Model.extend({
        parse : function __parseSearch(response) {
            console.log(response); // <-- CHECK HERE
            return response;
        },
        idAttribute : 'categoryId' // <-- FIX HERE
    }),
    comparator : 'categoryId' // <-- FIX HERE
});

self.CustColl(new CustCollection());
self.searchDatasource(new oj.CollectionTableDataSource(self.CustColl()));
```

Here I had a copy paste error, I forgot to change `idAttribute` as well.

So check your data source's response and fix accordingly.

The problem is that `ojTable` didn't find the key (==idAttribute) column's value on the current row, and without throwing a tantrum there, it silently moved on, and because of a missing null check, we are notified about a totally unrelated problem.

Comment: Thanks for this reply. I struggled with this, but as my idAttribute does exist I wouldn't have thought to double check. In my case, it was because the parse function converts my response to a different naming format (department_id to DepartmentId), and I wrongly assumed the idAttribute needed to reflect the response rather than the parsed response.